# Check if the value next to a certain cell is less than original value

Tags: excel, function, colors, spreadsheet

'A' and 'B' columns on sheet one:

- a - 100
- b - 200
- c - 600
- etc...

On sheet two col 'A' contains different than original 'B' Values. I need the background colors on sheet two to change green whenever the values are greater or equal to original values and red if not like

- a - 98*red
- b - 201*green
- a - 102*green
- a - 100*green
- c - 509*red
- c - 600*green

Pardon my English and Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two conditional formatting rules with custom formula:

Red:

```
=$B1<VLOOKUP($A1,Sheet1!$A:$B,2,FALSE)
```

Green:

```
=$B1>=VLOOKUP($A1,Sheet1!$A:$B,2,FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You!

That's excactly what I needed

Comment: @ArisGhazaryan please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.